# PyXML install - memmove does not exist on this platform

Tags: python, gcc

Im trying to install pyxml library with pip but i get following errors during installation:

```
extensions/expat/lib/xmlparse.c:75:2: error: #error memmove does not exist on this platform, nor is a substitute available
```

I've tried to reinstall gcc compilator .

Current version i've is: **gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3**

OS: Kubuntu 13.04.

Can i somehow reinstall memmove library? As far as i know, it is delivered with string.h lib.

Comment: There's no such thing as a `memmove` library; that's a standard C library function. Is `/usr/include/string.h` in place?

Comment: This is strange, lib/xmlparse.c is part of the expat library, not of pyxml, though expat is a dependency of pyxml. Can you check you have libexpat1 in your system? (Though it would be strange if you don't, it is a dependency of many packages.)

Comment: @larsmans string.h is in place

Comment: @volferine i've install **expat** but it wont help. And: libexpat1 is already the newest version.

Comment: Try installing its headers as well, that'll be `libexpat-dev` or something similar (check packages.ubuntu.com to be sure).

Comment: @larsmans libexpat-dev also already installed

Comment: Can you check what `distutils.sysconfig.get_config_h_filename()` returns (for me it's `/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h`), and if you have HAVE_MEMMOVE in the file?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same problem, also running kubuntu-13.04 (worked fine in 12.10.)

@volferine seems to be onto something. My `config_h` file is also `/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h`, and it did not contain the string `HAVE_MEMMOVE`.

To `pyconfig.h`, I appended:

```
#define HAVE_MEMMOVE 1
```

PyXML now appears to build for me. I filed a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1238244.

Comment: Actual for Debian 8 too.