# PyXML Ubuntu 13.1, error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, pyxml

struggling to install PyXML on UBuntu 13.1.0, As it is throwing the error:
 error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

I googled around a bit but could only find instructions to install python-dev but I have already done this (as demoed in the code below). I also added HAVE_MEMMOVE 1 to pyconfig.h

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks,

```
 ravin@Eowyn:~$ sudo easy_install PyXML
Searching for PyXML
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/PyXML/
Best match: PyXML 0.8.4
Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/pyxml/PyXML-0.8.4.tar.gz?modtime=1101741917&big_mirror=0
Processing PyXML-0.8.4.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-DrBxsQ/PyXML-0.8.4/setup.cfg
Running PyXML-0.8.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-DrBxsQ/PyXML-0.8.4/egg-dist-tmp-ae0fv1
warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'extensions/expat'
warning: no files found matching '*Makefile' under directory 'extensions/expat'
warning: no files found matching '*.dsp' under directory 'extensions/expat'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*/CVS/*' found anywhere in distribution
extensions/expat/lib/xmlparse.c:75:2: error: #error memmove does not exist on this platform, nor is a substitute available
 #error memmove does not exist on this platform, nor is a substitute available
  ^
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
ravin@Eowyn:~$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

[image]

Comment: Try creating a symlink from `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc` to `/usr/bin/gcc`.

Comment: it fails to create the link as /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc file exists

Comment: I did not read your post carefully.  It is likely a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PyXML install - memmove does not exist on this platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181102/pyxml-install-memmove-does-not-exist-on-this-platform)

Comment: I found that answer in my searches but it did not fix the issue:

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to install PyXML? It was written for older versions of python. Try using [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) it is simple to use and even supports [XPath](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax)

You may start with

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
```

and then continue with [parsing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml) or [manipulating](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file)

EDIT:

Known Issues from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/adspygoogle)

The installation of PyXML and cElementTree will fail on Ubuntu 13.04, which is why these are now optional. If you are trying to install adspygoogle on Ubuntu 13.04, you should avoid installing these dependencies. If you need to use either of these dependencies, there is currently a work-around that can be found in this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1238244/).

Comment: PyXML is used in the Adwords_Api client library provided by Google so to use the library code i need xml :(